# What options are there for chanukiah lighting in southern latitudes?

Tags: children-parenting, geography, chinuch-education, evening-night, menora-chanukia

What options are there for lighting chanukiyot in southern latitudes where younger children will be going to bed well before sunset?

Adults may stay up for lighting chanukiyot but what options are there for involving children in some form of candle lighting even if they're going to bed in daylight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you're far down as Cape Town at [33° 55′ 31″ S](http://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Cape_Town&params=33_55_31_S_18_25_26_E_type:city_region:ZA).

Candle lighting on the first day of Chanuka (this year, 5775) at sunset would be at 19:55 and if you wait for *night* then it's at 20:25.

However, one can light as early as [Plag HaMincha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zmanim#Plag_Hamincha) which will be at 18:25 - that may be the simplest way to get the children involved - light as early as Halachicaly possible.

([CYLOR disclaimer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-mi-yodeya) in place.)

Comment: I think your solution of lighting as early as possible is the best option. This year plag hamincha will be at 19:20 by the end of Chanuka here so they'll still get a few late bedtimes...

Comment: We're in Wellington (New Zealand) at over 41 degrees south - where, for example, candlelighting will be at 20:34 for the Shabbos during Chanuka.